# PHP check if event has started

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following mysql script to display a list of active / upcoming fixtures.

```
    Select * FROM schedule 
            WHERE schedule.gameDate > CURDATE() OR
                        ( schedule.gameDate = CURDATE() and schedule.gameTime > CURTIME() )
            GROUP BY schedule.tournament
            ORDER By schedule.gameDate
```

The above script works perfectly.

However, as an additional check to prevent a user from accessing a fixture which has expired im doing the following.

```
$curTime = date('H:i:s');
$curDate =  date('Y-m-d');    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule
         WHERE tournament = :tour AND weekNum = :round";
$stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->bindValue(':tour',$tournament);
$stmnt->bindValue(':round', $round);
$stmnt->execute();
$results = $stmnt->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $result){

    echo $eventDate = $result['gameDate'];
    echo $startTime = $result['gameTime'];

    if($curDate > $eventDate){
        echo '<h1> CURRENT ROUND ALLREADY STARTED</h1>';
        die();
}//if
else if($eventDate==$curDate && $curTime>$startTime){
        echo '<h1> CURRENT ROUND ALLREADY STARTED</h1>';
        die();
    }//else if  
}//foreach
```

**My Problem.**

The loop never passes the first IF statment which always results to true...

**DB Table**

[image]

When I echo the variables I get the following:

```
$curTime = 09:30:00
$curDate = 2017-19-03

$eventDate = 2017-03-21
$startTime = 13:00:00
```

I realize it is not the prettiest code but according to my little experience and logic it should pass both if statments...

Any advise appreciated

Comment: Try converting them to timestamps before comparing. I don't think comparing strings like that will give you a meaningful result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `strtotime()` in compare two date in php

**Replace**      `if($curDate > $eventDate)` **with**  `if(strtotime($curDate) > strtotime($eventDate))` and other comparison also

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to DateTime objects or timestamps to compare. String comparison will only check whether they are equal or not.

So:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$event = new DateTime($eventDate . ' ' . $startTime);
```

Then you can check whether dates are equal or later the same way you're already doing. See [Example #2 on the Date Diff page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) of the php website. E.g. `$now > $event`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It should be elseif.not else if. There should not be a space between else and if.